# To use the confluent schema registry and avro serializer in the spring application, how to do for json data input

Tags: apache-kafka, avro, spring-cloud-stream, confluent-schema-registry

Currently, I have used spring cloud stream github example, however I do not know how to transfer the manually typed objects into json format by providing from the existing json data. I can infer the avro schema using some tool from json data. However the problem is I do not want to use POJOs that is inferred from class in `import` using avro schema instead I want to use the existing json data. I am also confused about the application/json part, when I am using 
`curl -X POST`, maybe is there a way to feed the data in http request(add annotations in the send message part). Also, give an explanation of `@ResquestMapping`, and `@Enablebinding`, `@StreamListener`, when to use them.

Comment: Please limit your posts to a single question / problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To start off, you'd have to define a producer using the KafkaAvroSerializer rather than some StringSerializer or JSON one

> from the existing json data

You'd use a from the existing json data like Jackson or Gson to take JSON to a POJO by parsing it.

> the problem is I do not want to use POJOs that is inferred from class

POJO defines classes. They're not inferred

> using avro schema instead I want to use the existing json data.

JSON and Avro are different formats. You'd have to use some tool to translate them or manually parse JSON yourself and create an Avro record

> I am also confused about the application/json part, when I am using curl -X POST, maybe is there a way to feed the data in http request(add annotations in the send message part

Yes, headers define extra metadata in the request

```
curl -H 'Content-Type:application/json`
```

> @StreamListener, when to use them

When you're consuming events, not sending them

Comment: Hi, thank you and sorry for the combined question due to a hurry question post. In order to treat the JSON data in avro way, the only thing I can do is either to transfer the JSON data to POJOs as well as getting the schema (ex. infer the schema from JSON data) or to create an Avro object (with schema inferred) directly. For the first option, in spring cloud stream, after I transfer JSON data into POJOs, I think I can just set the dynamicSchemaGenerationEnabled.

Comment: For the latter option, is there any support API in spring to create a Avro object or I need to right a function to create use the native org.Apache.Avro framework.

Comment: I haven't use Spring. I don't think Spring has anything related to Avro. There is no way to create an Avro object with an inferred schema. A schema is required to create an Avro object.

Comment: Since I found some resources online like Kite framework that can infer schema from json data

Comment: I don't think that is actively developed anymore

Comment: Thank you for mentioning that, so in my case, what should be the reasonable flow? Parse Json using Jackson like software into POJO and use spring cloud stream dynamic schema generation or any other ways to send Json data into an Avro way.

Comment: Jackson has Avro libraries as well as JSON, fyi